# Scala - Convert column having comma separated numbers (currently string) to Array of Double in Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a column in DataFrame which is currently in String format having multiple comma separated double datatype values (mostly 2 or 3). Refer to below schema snapshot.

```
Sample : "619.619620621622, 123.12412512699"

root
 |-- MyCol: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to convert it to an Array of double which should look like below schema.

```
Desired : array<double>
[619.619620621622, 123.12412512699]

root
 |-- MyCol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element_value: double (containsNull = true)
```

I know how to do it on single string value. Now I want to to it on complete DataFrame column.

Is there any way this could be done using single/ double liner code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` + `cast` should do the job:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, split}

val df = Seq(("619.619620621622, 123.12412512699")).toDF("MyCol")

val df2 = df.withColumn("myCol", split(col("MyCol"), ",").cast("array<double>"))

df2.printSchema

//root
// |-- myCol: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Thanks.. this works! 
I was able to figure this out yesterday.. did same thing like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the starting point:

```scala
val spark: SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._

val df: DataFrame = ???
```

here is a solution based on UDF:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def toDoubles: UserDefinedFunction =
  udf { string: String =>
    string
      .split(",")
      .map(_.trim) //based on your input you may need to trim the strings
      .map(_.toDouble)
  }

df
  .select(toDoubles($"MyCol") as "doubles")
```

Edit: the `toDouble` conversion already trims the string